1920x1080 screen resolution disappeared. tried xrandr, no luck
Running 24.04 on custom desktop.
Screen turned itself off. upon restart resolution dropped to 1024x768. no option to change back.
Tried xrandr which puts the line back in for 1920x1080 on terminal, but it does not add it to the display resolution menu.
Restart removes the 1920x1080 line from the terminal list. Apparently I am using wayland, whatever that is
